# If a husband and wife were co-workers, would the wife need to be obedient in the workplace?

Tags: husband-wife, work

It seems likely that some Muslim husband and wives would happen to be co-workers.

**Question**: If a husband and wife were co-workers, would the wife need to be obedient in the workplace?

It's unclear to me how this dynamic would play out in the workplace.  It seems possible that conflicts of interest could arise, e.g. if the wife happened to be the husband's boss.  Or maybe "obedience" wouldn't apply in the workplace.

Comment: Simple pragmatic point: the wife needs the husband's permission to work as long as he provides for her, as far as I know. That's a bad strategic position if she wants to go against him in the workplace.

Comment: Interesting question, but as most scholars wouldn't really recommend a similar situation (and would consider working for a woman as rather optional) we could end up with no fatwa. So you should be aware that in such a case we'll have opinion-based answers. IMO the obedience issue is exaggerated in fatwas (especially of those scholars who relay too much on sunnah) .

Comment: @G.Bach Allah reveals the law. The implementation is upto those in authority. The problem you pointed out can be easily addressed by adding a compulsory contract by the state to women who work which will oblige their husbands to not interfere with their work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a husband and wife were co-workers, would the wife need to be obedient in the workplace?

If the wife is the boss then the husband must follow her official orders. That is because cheating is haram as stated in the following:

> Cheating is haraam, whether it is in buying and selling, or in exams, or any other matter, because of the general meaning of the words of the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him): “Whoever cheats is not one of us.”Narrated by Muslim, 102 from the hadeeth of Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him)
>
> https://islamqa.info/en/175744

---

> . It seems possible that conflicts of interest could arise,

That's haram big time as stated in the following verse:

> Sahih International: And do not approach the orphan's property except in a way that is best until he reaches maturity. And give full measure and weight in justice. We do not charge any soul except [with that within] its capacity. And when you testify, be just, **even if [it concerns] a near relative.** And the covenant of Allah fulfill. This has He instructed you that you may remember.
>
> Verse (6:152) - English Translation